# Spawning Google Chrome with Node js

Tags: node.js, macos, child-process

I am trying to spawn Google Chrome, and I can't seem to make anything work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 var cp = require('child_process');

 console.log("Spawning Chrome");

 chrome = cp.spawn('/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
     ['http://www.nodejs.org']);
```

Comment: Your code works fine on Mavericks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you may want to do instead is use OS X's `open` command.

`cp.spawn("/usr/bin/open", ["http://www.nodejs.org"])`

This will use the user's preferred browsers, instead of hardcoding Chrome AND it doesn't matter where (the user's browser) is installed.

(What might be happening with your current code is that something's getting tripped up with the spaces: you have escaped them, but I'm not sure if cp.spawn needs them escaped)